# ¿Cómo formatear número en Django en un template?

Tags: python, django

Tengo un proyecto en Django y estoy pasando mediante la base de datos precios de los productos, solo que al renderizarlos en el template aparecen así "1200000", pero necesito que aparezcan "1.200.000", ¿de qué manera se puede lograr esto?
Acá la porción del código donde renderizo el precio:

```
<p class="text-center py-2 border-t border-gray-600 mx-10">${{ producto.precio }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una expresión regular para insertar un punto cada tres números de esta forma.

```
import re

"(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)"
<p class="text-center py-2 border-t border-gray-600 mx-10">${{ re.sub("(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)", ".", producto.precio) }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

La aplicación `django.contrib.humanize` contiene el filtro [intcomma](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) que proporcionará el formato según la localización del contexto actual:

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load i18n %}
{% language 'es' %}
{{ producto.precio|intcomma }}
{% endlanguage %}
```